# Having trouble in installing Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: dual-boot, 15.04

I was trying to install Ubuntu in my system but some problem occurred as explained below. I am having elementary in my system and want to dual boot with Ubuntu.

1. Firstly I selected my pendrive from boot options
   [Screen 1](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=34qwplg&s=8#.VdwyTnWlyko)
2. After that following screen comes and get stuck at this.
   [Screen 2](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2m4w46t&s=8#.Vdwun3Wlyko)

Please help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue when I create bootable USB using "Unetbootin". Try "Universal USB Installer" or something else.

Answer (score 0):

If you are making a 15.04 USB bootable device from 14.04, it might not work well. You can use the dd command as a sudoer. Format and mount the pen drive. Assuming that the name of the ISO file is file_name.iso and it is saved in your Home directory and your pendrive is mounted at /dev/sdb, you can run this command:

```
sudo dd if=file_name.iso of=/dev/sdb
```

You won't get any immediate response but wait until the process finishes and you get the details of the records in and records out. After that, boot from the pen drive.